# Android Reflection - Android Jars

Tags: android, reflection

**Case 1**: Look at the code below. I am able to get Class and Method objects and it works well. Method I am trying to access is android.view.View::dispatchPointerEvent.

**Case 2**: When I replace class/Method with com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService::grantPermissionsLPw, I get NoMethodFoundException. Class was accessible though.

**Case 3**: When I replace class/Method with android.hardware.input.InputManager::injectInputEvent, I get NoMethodFoundException. Class was accessible though.

**Question is**: Why some of the android class/methods are accessible via reflection and some other not?

```
    Class _class = null;
    try {
        _class = Class.forName("android.view.View");
        Log.i("Test", "Class found");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Method method = null;
    try {
        Log.i("Test", "Pre-Method found");

        method = _class.getDeclaredMethod("dispatchPointerEvent",
                MotionEvent.class);

        Log.i("Test", "Method found");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Test","I failed."+e.getMessage()+e.toString());
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    Class _class = null;
    try {
        _class = Class.forName("com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService");
        Log.i("Test", "Class found");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Method method = null;
    try {
        Log.i("Test", "Pre-Method found");
        Class _class2 = Class.forName("android.content.pm.PackageParser$Package");

        method = _class.getDeclaredMethod("grantPermissionsLPw",
                _class2, boolean.class);

        Log.i("Test", "Method found");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Test","I failed."+e.getMessage()+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry but I cannot post comments, so have to post response)
Did you put the right method parameters? Where you have **MotionEvent.class**.

Comment: Yes, I did replace parameters as appropriate and also took care of private methods via SetAccessible true as indicated on other SO questions..

Comment: Are you executing inside app or emulator or just calling from an IDE project? If you are not in an emulator I suppose you are calling a stub and there is nothing to do.

Comment: The only thing I can say is "what android version are you running?" If I'm not wrong the com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService class appears in api 10. Please check your version.

Comment: I am way above 10.. I am using 16

Answer (score 0):

android.hardware.input.InputManager::injectInputEvent requires the android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS permission which is a system permission not available to apps. If you need to do this you'll have to root the device and sign your app as a system app.

Comment: But I am not calling it. Through reflection I am just trying to access it. If I do invoke and it fails I can understand. But NoMethodFoundException is whats very confusing.

Comment: if you just replace the class and method name from Case 2 or 3, it doesn't work. Code remains same. Only class and method name changes and it throws NoMethodFoundException. Don't want to repeat same code and make it complex to understand.

Comment: Well if you truly are only replacing the names of the class and method, then it's pretty obvious that aren't passing in the correct arguments for the new method. That would explain the NoMethodFoundException.